# Example of lvalues / rvalues yielded by member access operators

Tags: c++

I have found multiple questions regarding the lvalue yielded by the arrow operator and the lvalue or rvalue yielded by the dot operator, but the answers are not quite coherent.

Chapter 4.6 of the book C++ Primer says:

> The arrow operator requires a pointer operated and yields an lvalue. The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue; otherwise, the result is an rvalue.

Does the author only mean data members, or also member functions that can be used as an lvalue? Can someone give me an example where the behaviour of these two operators differs, and explain why that is?

Please excuse me if this has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: It's not simple see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: You cannot fetch the value of a member function with a dot or arrow operator at all. You can only call it. If `x` is a member function, then `a->x` has no value category because it is simply invalid.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. have a read of __Pending member function call__ from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @RichardCritten "are classified as prvalue expressions" ok

Answer (score 5):

The quote is much easier to understand with some examples. I'll start with the "dot" operator first.

### The "dot" operator

Lets consider data members first with a simple `Person` example:

```cpp
struct Person {
    std::string name;
};
```

In general when people use a `struct` or `class`, you'll normally see it accessed through a named-value which will always yield the standard/expected lvalue reference:

```cpp
auto person = Person{"Foo"}
std::string& name = person.name;
```

However, this doesn't always have to be an lvalue. This member access through the "dot" operator will propagate the refness of the object being accessed. That means that you can implicitly get an rvalue ref of `name` if `person` is an rvalue (XValue):

```cpp
auto person = Person{"Foo"};
std::string&& name = std::move(person).name;
```

<kbd>**[Try it Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dsbf8PGGf)**</kbd>

or as a temporary (PRValue):

```cpp
// Note: using a function call here so that the reference doesn't dangle
auto consume(std::string&&) -> void;
...
consume( Person{"Foo"}.name );
```

<kbd>**[Try it Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TesW4q6Ms)**</kbd>

This is what the quote is referring to when it says:

> The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue; otherwise, the result is an rvalue.

This value-propagation is somewhat true of member functions as well. Since C++11, it's been possible to [ref-qualify member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions) -- which will call the appropriate function based on the refness of the underlying object:

```cpp
class Person {
    ...
    auto get_name() && -> std::string&&;
    auto get_name() const & -> const std::string&;
    ...
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

...

auto person = Person{...};
person.get_name(); // calls 'get_name() const &'
std::move(person).get_name(); // calls 'get_name() &&'
```

<kbd>[**Try it Online**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TesW4q6Ms)</kbd>

**Note:** Unlike accessing a data member, the result of the *function call* need not actually match the value-category; this is just used for determining *which* function to call as a form of overload resolution.

### Arrow Operator

For the default arrow operator (e.g. not a custom `operator->`), it can only operate on **pointers**. Pointers, unlike references, don't contain the underlying value-category of the **pointee**; they only know the value category of the pointer itself.

For example, `std::move`ing a `Person*` will yield a `Person*&&` -- which is an rvalue of the pointer, but not of the underlying pointed object. For this reason, dereferencing through `operator->` can never yield an rvalue, since the pointee is never known to be an rvalue.

#### Custom `operator->` definitions

The Arrow operator is also interesting because, for a custom class, it can be overloaded by defining `operator->()` -- but this operator will still be constrained by the same problem as described above!

Any definition of `operator->` must return an object which either defines `operator->`, *or* is a pointer. This is done because any expression `a->b` in C++ will recursively call `operator->` until it reaches a pointer in order to perform the dereference. As we know from above, a pointer does not contain a value category -- so once we reach this point we cannot get an rvalue.

Even if you were to attempt to combine this with ref-qualified functions, such as:

```cpp
auto operator->() && -> SomeWrapper<T>;
```

you still won't be able to propagate the value-category to the reference because eventually it will come back down to a pointer which does not contain a value category.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: the C++ system of value categories is rather abstruse; the terms 'lvalue' and 'rvalue' really aren't the whole story, so if you want the full explanation of value categories in all its technical glory, I advise you to check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category as @Richard Critten said in the question comments.

Now, supposing you have a struct

```cpp
struct S{
  int member {5};
};
```

, the behaviour of the operators will differ when performing member access on temporary objects—since their addresses cannot be taken, member access can only take the form of the dot operator (since no pointer can be produced for the arrow operator):

```cpp
int x = S().member; // Ok, x = 5
int x = (&(S()))->member; // Error: cannot take address of temporary object
```

In this case, `S()` is an rvalue expression, and we can use the dot operator on it, but there isn't really a way to use the arrow operator on it.

Regarding "member functions that can be used as an lvalue", I'm assuming you mean functions that return an lvalue reference, e.g.

```cpp
struct S {
  int member {5};
  int& get_ref()
  {
    return member;
  }
}
```

where the returned lvalue reference can be written to; I don't believe that there is any functional difference with the normal member access case.